# using public key from certificate will throw error

Tags: node.js, ssl, x509certificate, auth0, x509

I plan to use auth0 with some very specific requirements. For that I need an https server based on a certificate and public key. I have downloaded the certificate from auth0 and I used the following command to extract the public key:

```
openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in yourfilename.cer > pubkey.pem
```

I then removed ---Begin--- and ---End--- from it. When using the cert and key for the https server, however, it doesnt work and I keep getting this error:

```
Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
```

My code:

```
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./certs/pubkey.pem', 'utf-8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('./certs/certificate.cer', 'utf-8');
const credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
```

Comment: A public key is not a private key. Have a look at the nonsense in line 1 of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to create a private key from a public key .pem file. I believe this is why you're getting the error from the server creation code.

This code works for example:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('./privateKey.key', 'utf8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('./certificate.crt', 'utf8');

const credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate };
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Add test route here. 
app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send("All good");
})

const server = https.createServer(credentials, app);
server.listen(8443);
```

Whereas if we try:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('./pubkey.pem', 'utf8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('./certificate.crt', 'utf8');

const credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Add test route here. 
app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send("All good");
})

const server = https.createServer(credentials, app);
server.listen(8443);
```

We'll get the error:

```
Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
```

You need a private key to create your https server, and this is not present in the certificate.